# Foreground service getting killed by the OS

Tags: android, service, foreground-service

I'm creating an app that captures location every 30 seconds. To do so, I've a foreground service and a handler in it that gets the latest location every 30 seconds. The app is working just fine for many devices with stock OS. But, on some devices like OnePlus, Panasonic, Vivo etc. the foreground service gets killed by the OS(sometimes the app too) even after changing the battery optimization status and the doze mode. I know that it is not possible to create a service in Android that does not die. Is there any way I can achieve what I'm trying to? Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Please check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
Add your code , what have you tried. Format your code to make it more readable

Answer (score 2):

First of all, yes you are right the operating system will stop services when resources are limited, so to get around this you state the type of the services while creating them as the following:
START_STICKY, START_NOT_STICKY, START_REDELIVER_INTENT...

read the last part of this article it talks about when to use which of them

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2010/02/service-api-changes-starting-with.html

Service.onStartCommand() callback that allows the service to better control how the system should manage it. The key part here is a new result code returned by the function, telling the system what it should do with the service if its process is killed while it is running.